# Entity Framework - Prevent Cache in Context

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity

I have a Entity Framework based Web API that reads and write data into Mssql Database. 
Context is great if you don't want to access database each time you want to access any data, because it is caching the data that you used before.

But my problem sarts here;

I have an crawler that works standalone and changes database. So, my web application context doesn't know what changed by the crawler. Because when I try to access to the data it shows me the data in context.

So, how can I prevent cacheing in context, how can I say that to read data from mssql for each request?

Answer (score 0):

If you know that an Entity was modified out of your current context, than you can reload it by means of [Reload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbentityentry.reload(v=vs.113).aspx) method:

Generic version could be looks like this:

```
 public T Reload<T>(T entity) where T : class
 {
    Context.Entry(entity).Reload();
    return entity;
 }
```

Btw you can avoid such as problems in most cases and especially in case of Web API/MVC  due to properly management of  EF context's life cycle (You have to create new instance of the context for each request)